# Audio Formats That Function With Multiple Streaming Devices/Software?

Tags: audio, streaming, encoding, compatibility

I'd like to know which audio encoding format(s), as part of a video container file, will stream with ***all*** of the following devices/apps:

- Apple TV 3
- Roku 3
- LG 2012 Smart TV MediaLink (Plex front end)
- Plex (for OS X, iOS & Roku)
- iTunes (for OS X & iOS)

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

MP3 is the most common, so I'd assume it'll work on all non-Apple devices (I know it will work on Apple)